# Normalize values of parameters in pytorch

Tags: parameters, pytorch

I was following this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/conditional-random-field-tutorial-in-pytorch-ca0d04499463 to understand CRF better. Tutorial also has associated code.

pytorch model has a 2x3 matrix as parameters (in self.transition). The values are log of these probabilities:

```
p(Yt = Fair | Yt-1 = Fair),   p(Yt = Fair | Yt-1 = Biased),   p(first dice is fair)
p(Yt = Biased | Yt-1 = Fair), p(Yt = Biased | Yt-1 = Biased), p(first dice is Biased)
```

Clearly it has lot more degree of freedom and instead of 6 we only need 3 parameters.

What I need is, after each step of opt.step(), I want to normalize these parameters so that they reflect true probabilities.

I would like to update self.transition as:

```
self.transition = torch.log(
                    torch.exp(self.transition
                   )/torch.sum(
                        torch.exp(self.transition), 0
                            )
                           )
```

But I can't update it, so I tried instead as:

```
norm_val = torch.log(
        torch.exp(self.transition
                 )/torch.sum(
                    torch.exp(self.transition), 0
                            )
                        )
    self.transition.requires_grad = False
    self.transition -= self.transition
    self.transition += norm_val
    self.transition.requires_grad = True
```

Still I can't do it. If I initialize self.transition by creating *nn.Parameter*, then it does not update these parameters anymore. How can I normalize the model parameter after each opt step?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-do-weight-normalization-in-last-classification-layer/35193/3

Essentially I need to do this after each opt.step:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    self.transition.data.exp_()
    self.transition.data.div_(torch.sum(model.transition.data, dim=0))
    self.transition.data.log_()
```